# @row_number with virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I use a virtual layer that numbering and order features with their ID.
Their IDs are previously calculated by using `@row_number` in the field calculator.

So my workflow is to create `ID` with `@row_number`, then I can create the virtual layer.

My aim is to skip this manual step (filling `ID` by `@row_number` in field attribute) and managing row number directly in the virtual layer.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by line_ID, line_pcent) as new_ID 
FROM 
(
select p.*,
       l.id line_ID,
       ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry))) as line_pcent
from myPolygon p
 join myLine l
 on st_intersects(l.geometry, p.geometry)
)
```

In this case, I first have to create the `id` of the layer `myLine l` : this is the step I would like to skip. I would like my virtual layer works without the need of having `id` defined in the layer `myLine l`

```
 select p.*,
           l.id line_ID
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a row number as long as there is some other field to use in the `OVER` parameter, doesn't matter if it's non-unique. Apparently, using `geometry` field works (tested using shapefile datasource), so you could try the following:

```sql
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by line_ID, line_pcent) as new_ID 
FROM 
(
select p.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by l.geometry) as line_ID,
       ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry))) as line_pcent
from myPolygon p
 join myLine l
 on st_intersects(l.geometry, p.geometry)
)
```